# How do I cite this apparently unpublished paper?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing

How do I cite the paper [The fundamental distinction between brains and turing machines](http://web.mit.edu/asf/www/PopularScience/Friedman_BrainsAndTuringMachines_2002.pdf), by Andrew Friedman?

Comment: I believe that you may want to add more context. Are you adding references by hand or are you using bibtex or the like? You can always add author, title and so on fields by hand if you do not find the database entry online.

Comment: Could well be that it is published. You may find here someone who knows the answer to the question whether or not this journal is reliable, but IMHO this is not necessarily a LaTeX question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to cite something you found online that does not seem to be published elsewhere (in a journal, as part of a collection/book/conference proceedings, ...) you can always fall back to `@online`.

From the PDF alone you already have the `author`, a `title` and you can infer the `year`. Naturally you have a URL and the access date, so you could have

```
@online{friedman,
  author  = {Friedman, Andrew},
  title   = {The Fundamental Distinction Between Brains and Turing Machines},
  year    = {2002},
  url     = {http://web.mit.edu/asf/www/PopularScience/Friedman_BrainsAndTuringMachines_2002.pdf},
  urldate = {2019-06-19},
}
```

---

According to Andrew Friedman's web page http://web.mit.edu/asf/www/popular_science.shtml and his CV https://asfriedman.physics.ucsd.edu/MITResume/AndrewFriedmanCV.pdf this article was published in the *Berkeley Scientific Journal*, Vol. 6, Issue 1, Spring 2002, p. 28-33. The cover image of the journal in question available at http://afriedman.org/AndysWebPage/BSJ/Spring2002Cover.html as well as the short summary of the contents of the Spring 2002 issue at https://bsj.berkeley.edu/read-the-bsj/past-issues/ seem to corroborate that story.

Unfortunately, older volumes of the BSJ are not digitally available in their entirety. See also https://bsj.berkeley.edu/read-the-bsj/past-issues/. Newer versions can be found at https://escholarship.org/uc/our_bsj.

One may feel a bit uneasy about citing a publication with data that one could not verify completely and that is not particularly helpful to the reader (the BSJ issue in question is not available online and I doubt that a lot of people have access to the journal through their libraries), but if that is not an issue for you, you could also cite this entry as an `@article`

```
@article{friedman,
  author  = {Friedman, Andrew},
  title   = {The Fundamental Distinction Between Brains and Turing Machines},
  year    = {2002},
  journal = {Berkeley Scientific Journal},
  volume  = {6},
  number  = {1},
  issue   = {Spring},
  url     = {http://web.mit.edu/asf/www/PopularScience/Friedman_BrainsAndTuringMachines_2002.pdf},
  urldate = {2019-06-19},
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is what you had in mind. And the question does not seem to be about (La)TeX/BibTeX an awful lot, but maybe it helps.

Comment: Hey, moewe, congrats on the 100k landmark! Cheers!

Comment: @gusbrs Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cite it as `@Misc`, and give as much detail as you can get (e.g., URL where to find it, where it is cited, ...).